# How to annotate Django QuerySet with other object using Subquery

Tags: python, django

In Django version 1.11, [Subquery expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) were added. I was hoping to use this feature to select a related model object based on some filters.

This is an example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')   
Post.objects.annotate(newest_commenter_email=Subquery(newest.values('email')[:1]))
```

I would like to do the same, but instead of just annotating with the "`newest_commenter_email`" in this scenario, I'd like the whole `Comment` object saved to a `newest_comment` annotation, like so:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')   
Post.objects.annotate(newest_comment=Subquery(newest[:1]))
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Maybe you could start from the comment model? `Comment.objects.filter(post=pk).order_by('-created_at').select_related('post')[:1]`. Then you preoloaded the `Post` object with the most recent comment. This way you get the whole Post and Comment model.

Comment: I have a library in the works for this.  It's actually not too difficult, at least with Postgres.  I'll post an answer once I get it in a clean state.

Answer (score 2):

You want to filter of the related model, hence this case I feed `Prefetch()` is one of the best options I can think about

You can read about it from here [Django1.1 Prefetch Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects)

and this is an example of what you're looking for

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch
newest = Comment.objects.filter(do_your_filters_here)   
Post.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("comments", queryset=newest, to_attr="newest_comments"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You ommited `values` on the subquery, try this:

```
Post.objects.annotate(newest_commenter=Subquery(newest.values('author')[:1]))
```

where 'author' is the "commenter" field on Comment model.

Comment: I think that was intended.  He wants to annotate the entire object, not just a single 'author' field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. You can only annotate with a basic type values, not with the object. The basic reason for this is that result of SQL query is a table with all its cells are basic values, not nested tables.
In order to do what you want we need SQL to support nested tables and Django to be able to convert nested tables into nested objects. I don't think that's ever going to happen.
So, in order to get several fields of related object you should repeat annotation for each field:

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    newest_commenter_email=Subquery(newest.values('email')[:1]),
    newest_commenter_username=Subquery(newest.values('username')[:1]),
)
```

Don't be afraid of performance issues due to executing the same query for each field. SQL engine is smart enough to see that query is the same and to cache its value

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Brobin -

```
Comment.objects.filter(post=pk).order_by('created_at').select_related('post')[:1]
```

If you really want to go from the Post model though do this -

```
q = (
  Comment
  .objects
  .filter(
    pk=Subquery(
      Comment
     .objects
     .filter(post=OuterRef('post'))
     .order_by('-created')
     .values('pk')
     [:1]
    )
  )
)

Post.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('comment_set', queryset=q)).all()
```

Unfortunately we cannot slice in the outer query for `q` because django disallows it.  So we slice inside a subquery and then filter on the outer query.