# Unknown output_field type in Subquery in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Parent1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Parent2(models.Model):
    parent1 = models.ForeignKey(Parent1)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent1 = models.ForeignKey(Parent1)
    parent2_label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other fields
```

I am trying to execute the below queries:

```
parent1 = Parent1.objects.first()
sq = Child.objects.filter(
    parent1=OuterRef("parent1"), parent2_label=OuterRef("label")
)
parents_2 = Parent2.objects.filter(parent1=parent1).annotate(
    children=Subquery(sq)
)
```

So basically what I am trying to execute is if `Child` model had a `fk` to `Parent2` then I would have `prefetch`ed the related `child` instances of the `Parent2` instances. Now at present there is no `fk` relation between `Child` and `Parent2`. The relation is based on the `label` field between those two. `fk` will be added later but before that for backwards compatibility I have to execute this query.

Now when I try to execute this query then I am getting the following error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field
```

I am using `Postgresql` db. Now what will be the `output_field` for the above query that I have to pass?

So basically what I am trying to achieve through the subquery is this:

```
# this is not a working example.
parents_2 = Parent2.objects.filter(parent1=parent1)
for parent in parents_2:
    children = Child.objects.filter(parent1=parent1, parent2_label=parent.label)
    parent.annotate(children=children)
```

I want the `children` to be a nested object with each parent_2 in the queryset.

Comment: Do you expect the annotation `children` to return a queryset of all the children of that parent? I don't see how that could be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783587/how-to-annotate-django-queryset-with-other-object-using-subquery You could use [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) to have the subquery return an array of children IDs, or something similar.

Comment: Yes. For each `parent2`, I want `children` to be a list of dicts of the related `child` instances. Relation meaning child instances that have parent1 fk and parent2 labels of that parent2 instances.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform I have added an example code. Is it possible to achieve without looping and using a subquery?

Comment: I don't think so, no. Try to picture how the result of the query would look like in Postgres; the `children` annotation is just a single column in that result table, so the annotation must be a single value of a Postgres data type. When building a query with Django, you can declare the type of the column with the `output_field` argument of an expression. But there is no output_field for Django querysets, model instances or python dictionaries, so you can't have the result of the annotation be of those types.